# Render pdf before complete loading in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, mozilla, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

How to start rendering pdf files before they are completely loaded on pdf.js . I am using pdf.js in following way - `example.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=<pdf_file_url>`. Thank you.

Comment: Are all the PDF files Linearized (Fast Web View)? If not, then pdf.js has to wait for the PDF to be completely loaded (this is a limitation of the PDF format, not pdf.js)

Comment: I loaded pdf https://storage.googleapis.com/mlbu/1xh60cjoadk1kvxnik-me21101-fluid-mechanics-pre-midsem-notes.pdf on firefox, it started rendering pdf before it was completely loaded. but this is not happening with my case. So pdf must be linearized as firefox is able to do it and it uses pdf.js as pdf viewer. So how is firefox able to do this, i have searched for the solution everywhere. not found yet.

Comment: That file is not linearized. Why do you think firefox is rendering before the download is complete? Check the network tab, that will show you the actual timings.

Comment: but i am able to see first pages and pages following as soon as it starts loading and pdf is yet to complete loading. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-973Nogmh6ew/XfCALdEBF2I/AAAAAAAAHPg/nLbvO2FdLgIKL4-Vt57walgP1JFoa-W3ACLcBGAsYHQ/s0/Screenshot%2Bfrom%2B2019-12-11%2B11-03-48.png

Comment: I definitely see that it takes longer and longer to show the 1st page in pdf.js, the larger the non-linearized PDF file is that I try to view. I think the confusion is that the "loading bar" that pdf.js shows is not a downloading progress bar, but is measuring more/else. Again, it is essentially impossible to render the 1st page of a non-linearized PDF, without having access to all the data. This is because the resources to draw the page can be anywhere, and non-linearized PDF files are read from the end (xref table is at end of file).

Comment: @last_fix did you find any solution? I am linearizing my pdfs. They are working fine in firefox but not in chrome. I am using and iframe to load pdfs.

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto nopes...